# How to search segment in picture

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I want to find straight lines marked in the image, the coordinates point A, point B is the beginning and end of the segment. Please help me!
img:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnjvH.jpg)
source:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1stVm.jpg)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is called the "Hough Transform"

You could experiment using something like Mathlab, and then implement it using opencv houghtransform.

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/houghlines.cpp

Comment: I understand the idea, but the search coordinates two points A and B, the hazelnut do?